# Is there an easy way to investigate if AccessController.doPrivileged() is really needed?

Tags: java, policy

I have this code that attaches a JavaServer to the RMIRegistry, which is done in a PrivilegedAction

```
        //start javaengineserver
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() 
        {
            public Object run() 
            {
                try
                {
                    startServer(port, getSession());
                } catch (RmiException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    AWTSwingErrorDialog.show(e, "Error while attaching JavaEngineServer to rmiregistry.exe");
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
```

I found some other Questions about the `doPrivileged` method, and they all say that there are some comands that need the extra permissions like getting Environment Variables.

So i looked threw the code behind the `startServer(port, session)` method and i haven't found anything that looks like it needs extra permissions, but is there a way to confirm that, other than Test all the usages and functionality by hand?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a (reliable) easy way.  There is an unreliable way though: temporarily replace that code with something that just calls `startServer`, and try running it in a security sandbox.

I suspect that the `doPrivileged` call is needed though.  A method with that name and a `port` parameter is likely to try to create / bind / listen on a `ServerSocket`.  The latter will fail if the `SecurityManager.checkListen` method does not allow the operation ... which it won't do in a typical sandbox.  (We don't normally want untrusted code to be able to start stealth network services ...)

Comment: Thanks a lot! In fact the method calls the bind xor the rebind method of the RMI Registry. I tried starting it without the doPrivileged() Method, and everything seems to work... And i found some problems according the SecurityManager with RMI.bind, but none of these seem to be fixed by calling the bind method with privileged access... Something is telling me that it is needed, but it runs fine without it..

Comment: @Oli - under the covers, those RMI methods are likely to do a serversocket bind.  Alternatively, there may be a specific permission related to RMI.  Either way, I think a security check is likely.  If you are not seeing that, check the policy settings of the sandbox you are using.

Comment: okay, so if the policy settings are tight enough the operation will fail without doPriviledged?